# ZF2 - Merge assets using Apache's AliasMatch

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2, apache2, apache2.2

I have the following application structure for a ZF2 application:

```
myapplication
 -->config
 -->data
 -->module [This directory is empty, as all my modules are in the vendor dir]
 -->public
    -->.htaccess
    -->index.php
 -->vendor
    -->Module1
       -->assets
          -->css
          -->js
          -->images
       -->config
       -->src
       -->view
       -->Module.php
    -->Module2
       -->assets
          -->css
          -->js
          -->images
       -->config
       -->src
       -->view
       -->Module.php
    -->Module3
       -->assets
          -->css
          -->js
          -->images
       -->config
       -->src
       -->view
       -->Module.php
```

As you can see, all my asset files are nicely organized in it's own module. However, I would like any asset to be accessible using the following URL:

```
http://myapplication/css/xyz.css

http://myapplication/js/xyz.js

http://myapplication/images/xyz.jpg
```

How can I achieve this? The simplest way I found was to use an `aliasmatch` apache directive in my vhost.
However, I couldn't get it working right..

```
AliasMatch /(css|js|images)/(.*) C:/Users/myapplication/vendor/[MODULE_NAME]/assets/$1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think you don't should go over rewrites to achieve this, as every resource you want to use requires that they are accessible over your `public` folder in zf2 but your modules are "outside" this public folder.

this is the reason why rewrites won't work.

so either you create your own module that handels the asset requests, go to every module asset folder and deliver it over the `public` or you may have a look at this repository https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager which handels this for you.

Comment: The assetmanager module doesn't look like the only optimized way to do it.. Making PHP calls to every resource is painfully slow in large prod environments. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: yeah as our co-worker comes with this module that was in my head too, any other option that was in my head lead into some php calls (copy the source to public if not present, compare the file hash with module asset - if equal don't copy - present public file) - currently i have no other idea how to make this in any other way

Comment: @Jake `Is there any other way to do this?` Yes, with AssetManager, cache your assets in production environments ->  https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager/wiki/Caching

Comment: I cache all the assets in the web root when using AssetManager in production. This works perfectly. Also, try to prefix the assets path with module name like http://myapplication/my-module/css/xyz.css to avoid collision between modules assets.